# Facebook like button solution

Tags: php, facebook

Well, I found this Facebook like button code from Facebook Developers page and i add this to www.favoritebd.com. It's working but **DIDN'T COUNT THE NUMBER OF LIKE !**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script> 

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.favoritebd.com" data-send="false" 
data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Any idea or solution, I need if anyone like this then count will be shown..

Comment: I can see 2 likes.  How many do you see?

Comment: If you fixed it, please let us know how, I am facing the same problem.

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/10150547988904868 I see none listed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the above code example.  More than likely when facebook went to scrape the page for og tags, facebook couldn't reach it.  When someone tried again, and facebook could eventually scrape it.

Comment: !OH @Lix, It's right. It's didn't show any count because of i was logged in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everythings okay I just clicked the button and it returned "2 People Like This"

Comment: One more questions @Eric I've several news in my website so i want a like button for every post, how can i do this. can  you tell me please..

Comment: I believe each post needs to have a separate link if you want it to appear on Facebook. But i'm going to look into it

Comment: http://hillarsaare.com/multiple-facebook-like-buttons-on-one-page/ I hope this helps